# C++ Operator priority =, * and ++

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I have a question with this pointer value assignment:

```
*p++ = *q++;
```

According to 
[Operator Priority Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

The priorities of operators are "++" > "*" > "=".

But the result of the above statement does the assignment "=" first, as the following

```
*p = *q;
p++;
q++;
```

Why?

Comment: Compare and contrast with `*++p = *++q;`.

Comment: ++ is the same as * (* for pointers, not * for multiplication).  So at that point it becomes undetermined

Comment: @NerfHerder ... what?

Comment: @NerfHerder Postfix operators have higher precedence than prefix operators.

Comment: @NerfHerder That would mean it’s unclear whether `p` or `*p` is incremented. Not really.

Comment: This question should not be downvoted.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig, Brian, you are correct.  I didn't see the two entries for postfix/prefix.  And even for prefix, associativity is right to left so it is deterministic.  My bad.

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks! Now I can see the difference

Comment: Yawn. More miscomprehension of token parsing precedence. This is asked incredibly frequently on SO. A few months ago I had to correct a University professor with 9 published programming books... and he still couldn't get it. :( Evaluation order and operator precedence are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post-increment operator increments its operand **after its value has already been computed.** The pointer dereference therefore occurs on the values the pointers held before this line. However, the precedence you give is correct; the expression is indeed equivalent to

```
(*(p++)) = (*(q++))
```

Comment: I wouldn't show it with the ++ inside the parentheses, since that's done afterwards.

Comment: @NerfHerder Why not? The two statements (with and without parens) are completely equivalent and therefore have the same semantics. If you are saying that the OP's code is equivalent to `((*p)++) = ((*q)++)` then you would be wrong.

Comment: @NerfHerder its done *before*. You're discounting the temp-val. Postfix `++` is not done "afterward". The old value is temp'ed, the increment is done, and then the old value (from temp) is used for the outlying operation. That's how the operator works (and I am continually perplexed by how often it is *incorrectly* taught in academia).

Comment: Okay... it's written correctly, as long you keep in mind that the increments are not done until after the assignment is done.  Which is where the confusion is happening on this question.

Comment: @WhozCraig - interesting.  I hadn't seen that description before, but it makes sense.  I had read that it can be compiler dependent, but that might have been for early versions of C++

Comment: @NerfHerder Simplest example I can think of: [see it live](http://ideone.com/F3bKbw).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Never knew the increment in postfix increment was sequenced before the value calculation... I doubt that's really what you wanted to say.

Comment: @Deduplicator yea, it never comes out the same way twice no matter how many times I say it. The description after that opening sentence is probably much better as an example.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect.  The compiler may cause the operand to be incremented any time between the previous sequence point and before the next; in this case, the only sequence points are the full expression.  Depending on the hardware, and how the compiler generates code, the pointers in memory could be incremented before the values are used (but the compiler must use the old values).

Comment: @NerfHerder (and @WhozCraig): The only thing the standard says about when the "++" is done (when the pointer is modified, a side effect) is that it must occur after any sequence point preceding the operation, and before any sequence point following the operation.  It might occur as the first thing in the statement, or the last, or anywhere in between.

Comment: @JamesKanze My copy of the standard says: "The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the modification
of the operand object."

Comment: @WhozCraig Your description is as inaccurate as that of NerfHerder.  On some architectures, for example, the compiler might do the incrementation first, then use a register + contant addressing mode with -n (where n is the size of the object) as the constant; another compiler on a different architecture might defer all of the incrementations until the end of the full expression.  A compiler could use a temporary, as you describe, but I don't think that that is the most common implementation.

Comment: @Brian That would be a change with respect to earlier versions; there was no sequence point for `++` in the past.

Comment: @JamesKanze For C++03: "After the result is
noted, the value of the object is modified by adding 1 to it". Either way, I don't see what your point is. You said the compiler must use the old values. I believe I am saying the same thing. I am not making any statements about unobservable behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are post-fix operators, not pre-fix!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an important distinction.  An operator has a value, and
it may have side effects.  In the case of postfix `++`, the value is the
value *before* the incrementation, and the side effect is thhe
incrementation.  What is used in the expression is the value.  The side
effects may occur at any time before the end of the full expression (in
pre-C++11 terms, but the actual effect hasn't changed); a compiler might
start by incrementing the two pointers, saving their previous values in
registers and using them in the rest of the expression, or by using the
values directly from memory, and deferring the incrementation of both
pointers until the end of the expression.  Or any combination of
operations which results in the same observable behavior.