# String concatenation using pointers in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am concatenating a string (t) at the end of another string (s) in this code but stuck in the use of operators and their precedence in the loop ( while() )

> 1.`while(*s++);` doesn't do the work
>
> 2.`while(*s)  ++s;`   does

But what is the difference between them ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void strcat(char *, const char *);

int main(void){
    char s[100] = "Aditya ";
    char t[100] = "Kumar";
    strcat(s, t);
    printf("%s ", s);
    return 0;
}

void strcat(char * s, const char * t){
    while(*s)
        s++;

    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

Why in the strcat() function in first while `while(*s++);` doesn't concatenate the string but `while(*s) s++;` does I guess they work the same way ?

Comment: First `*s` is evaluated and then `s++` ?

Comment: Please elaborate with reference to operator precedences.

Comment: Because of extra one increment in the first variant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Operator priority =, \* and ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850172/c-operator-priority-and)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp no, it's not a duplicate of that. Here the issue is incrementing the pointer no matter what, failing the next loop because s if 1 too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they aren't equivalent.

```
while(*s++);
```

increments the pointer no matter what, so when `*s` is `\0`, the pointer is incremented once more. And the concatenation happens *after* the nul-terminator. The rest of the buffer contains zeroes so it doesn't crash but it doesn't do the job.

```
while(*s) { s++; }
```

stops when `*s` is `\0`. So no extra incrementation is performed.

Comment: To be honest, I answered because it took me a while to figure that out :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Your "a while" was approximately 20 seconds to my estimation :P

Comment: Does it mean that it is a nice question ?

Comment: @Adityakumar Let the score speak for it.

Comment: at least it's not a blatant undefined behaviour / wall of code question  like we see all the time.

Comment: It‘s an interesting brain-twister but not a suitable real-world solution for string concatenation because of the missing boundary checking. Only strings that are guaranteed to be null-terminated and not to exceed 100 characters (together!) are allowed. Otherwise memory overrun occurs.

Comment: @wra why 100 characters?

Comment: @savram "Why 100?" --> `char s[100]`

Comment: @EugeneSh.you're too kind :)